# Is there a way to updateData without scroll to top?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator 4.0.5.

To update data I'm using `table.updateOrAddData(data)`. It works fine but there is one side effect - this method *scroll top* the whole table.

I can't use `table.replaceData(data)` because of having custom tooltips (with images) for some cells. `table.replaceData(data)` will create new nodes and I will have to create new tooltips. So tooltips will re-appear on each data replace. This behavior is undesired.

Is there a way to update a date without *scroll top*? Maybe some hack?

**Update:**

There is a simplified constructor code:

```js
const table = new Tabulator('#selector', {
    index: 'my_id',
    selectable: true,
    responsiveLayout: 'hide',
    layout: 'fitColumns',
    columns: [
        {
            field: 'thumbnail',
            resizable: false,
            cssClass: 'tooltip-container',
            formatter: (cell) => {
                let imgSrc = cell.getValue();
                return (
                    `<div class="tool-tip tool-tip__center">
                        <img class="tool-tip__icon" src="${imgSrc}">
                        <p class="tool-tip__info">
                            <img src="${imgSrc}">
                        </p>
                    </div>`
                );
            },
            headerSort: false,
        },
        // other columns
    ],
});
```

So in the *formatter* I create image which will be shown in the cell (class `tool-tip__icon`) and tooltip which will be shown on hover (`.tool-tip:hover .tool-tip__info {display: block;}`).

And when I do `.replaceData(newData)` (it may be very often) the tooltip is flickering. Because of the table is re-rerendering with new nodes.

Comment: If you are adding your custom tooltips in your cell formatters or row formatters that should not be a problem.

Any chance you could post your table constructor in your question so we can understand a bit more about how it is configured

Comment: @OliFolkerd, thank you for your support. I updated the question with simplified code and put some explanation under it. Thank you

Comment: How are you creating the tooltips, are you using a plugin? If so that should be included in the formatter too

Comment: No plugins. It is plain CSS. If you hover over the cell, the `tool-tip__info` block get `display: block;` from CSS rule.

Even if it will be a plugin and I will put a tooltip creation to the *formatter*. Anyway `.replaceData()` is creating new nodes. So tooltip will be re-created. And if "previous" tooltip was visible (mouse over the cell) - it will blink. 

I hope my explanation was clear. I may record the video to show behavior. 

I think `.replaceData()` won't work. Is there a way to hack `.updateOrAddData()` to do not scroll on top?

Comment: Ahh i see you were concerned with a blink, sorry i thought you were concerned about having to regenerate the tooltip. my misunderstanding there. neither the updateData or updateOrAddData function should scroll to the top of the screen, they are in situ updates, the list may move if elements are inserted that cause it to move but there should not be a "scroll to top", could you create a code pen or js fiddle that replicates the issue, i cant seem to replicate it here

Comment: It's great that we came to an agreement. Maybe my initial problem's explanation was unclear. I will try to re-create this behavior with code pen. It may be not so easy because of the environment is specific. I'm constantly receiving data updates via Web Socket and updating (replacing) table with this data.